# Explanation of the output of this program:

Tags: c++

So the vector is supposed to have the following in it:
32, -64, -1, -1, 2, -4, 8, -16, 32

However, I don't really understand how? Can someone please explain? Any help is appreciated.

```
vector<int>vv(3,-1);
for(; vv[0]<10; vv[1] *=-2)
{
    vv.push_back(vv[1]);
    vv[0]=vv[vv.size()-1];
}
```

Comment: Use a *debugger* and step through the code line by line while monitoring the involved variable sand their values.

Comment: I tried checking but it said 16 bit application not supported by 64 bit windows.

Comment: Find a way to install a development environment which is not Turbo C on your computer.

Comment: Visual Studio 2017 Community is free: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/

Comment: I am using notepad++ and compiler is MINGW and I run my code directly from command line. But i'll try using Visual studio.

Comment: `vv[0]==vv[vv.size()-1];` ... one presumes that is supposed to just be `=`? Otherwise, infinite loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> explain?

Debugger is a better choice, but you are allowed to add cout's to illustrate the progress of the code.

---

```
// Note: -std=c++17 supports the 'using list'

#include <iostream>
using std::cout, std::cerr, std::endl, std::hex, std::dec, std::cin; // c++17

#include <vector>
using std::vector;

#include <string>
using std::string;

class T985_t // ctor and dtor are compiler provided defaults
{
public:
   int operator()() { return exec(); }  // functor entry

private: // methods

   int exec()
      {
         vector<int>vv(3,-1);
         show(vv, "\n  a ");         // ADD initial show

         for(; vv[0]<10; vv[1] *=-2)
         {
            vv.push_back(vv[1]);
            show(vv, "\n  b ");      // ADD show

          //vv[0]==vv[vv.size()-1];  warning: value computed is not used [-Wunused-value]
          // previous line causes infinite loop

            vv[0]=vv[vv.size()-1];
            show(vv, "\n  c ");      // ADD show
         }
         show(vv, "\n  d ");         // ADD final show
         return 0;
      }

   void show(vector<int>& iVec, string lbl )
      {
         cout << lbl;
         for (auto i : iVec)
            cout << i << "  ";
         cout << endl;
      }

}; // class T985_t

int main(int , char**) { return T985_t()(); }  // a functor
```

Output:  Stepping through the progress, 1 change at a time.

```
  a -1  -1  -1  

  b -1  -1  -1  -1  

  c -1  -1  -1  -1  

  b -1  2  -1  -1  2  

  c 2  2  -1  -1  2  

  b 2  -4  -1  -1  2  -4  

  c -4  -4  -1  -1  2  -4  

  b -4  8  -1  -1  2  -4  8  

  c 8  8  -1  -1  2  -4  8  

  b 8  -16  -1  -1  2  -4  8  -16  

  c -16  -16  -1  -1  2  -4  8  -16  

  b -16  32  -1  -1  2  -4  8  -16  32  

  c 32  32  -1  -1  2  -4  8  -16  32  

  d 32  -64  -1  -1  2  -4  8  -16  32
```

Comment: Well, great, thanks. I didn't know we could make the main function, functor as well.